# WP Woo - checking if an endpoint exists everytime a link is called

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

**Update:**

Noone called veto! against my solution, so *I Am assuming* this is okay to work this way.

---

**The Question / The Solution:**

This refers to my previous question:

[WP Woo - custom endpoint is deleted after saving Woo settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116434/wp-woo-custom-endpoint-is-deleted-after-saving-woo-settings)

I didn't see any other solution but to force checking if the endpoint exists every single time the link is called.

I am wondering: what could be a drawback of such approach?

The code I ended up with (tested several times, seems to be working properly):

```
add_action('template_redirect', array($this, 'check_the_endpoint'));

function check_the_endpoint() {
    global $wp;
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if( ! empty($wp->query_vars['attachment']) && $wp->query_vars['attachment'] == 'moje-punkty') {
            echo 'moje-punkty - 404 error';

            add_rewrite_endpoint( 'moje-punkty', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
            $this->foc_points_flush_rewrite_rules();

            header( 'Location: ' . home_url( $wp->request ));
        }
        else if( isset($wp->query_vars['moje-punkty'])) {
            echo 'moje-punkty - works!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'any other page';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Noone? No?
So here, my solution to ever-disappearing endpoint and how to bring it back - vide the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an answer if anybody faced same problem:

```
add_action('template_redirect', array($this, 'check_the_endpoint'));

function check_the_endpoint() {
    global $wp;
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if( ! empty($wp->query_vars['attachment']) && $wp->query_vars['attachment'] == 'moje-punkty') {
            echo 'moje-punkty - 404 error';

            add_rewrite_endpoint( 'moje-punkty', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
            $this->foc_points_flush_rewrite_rules();

            header( 'Location: ' . home_url( $wp->request ));
        }
        else if( isset($wp->query_vars['moje-punkty'])) {
            echo 'moje-punkty - works!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'any other page';
        }
    }
}
```

where, obvoulsy, every **ECHO** and **ELSE IF** and **ELSE** would be deleted - this was for testing purposes added, only.